# Do while loop keeps looping c++

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

So, I want this program to keep prompting when the number of digits isn't 16, that part worked, but whenever I try to input 16 digits it loops without letting me type anything in again. This is what I wrote:

---

```
do{

    cout<<"insert number pls: ";
    cin>>number;
    
    //counting digits
    number_count = 0;
    while(number != 0){
        number = number/10;
        number_count++;
    }

}while(number_count != 16);


cout<<"done"<<endl;
```

---

I tried to do it with `(number_count != 1)` until `(number_count != 10)` and they worked, it only started not working from 11, why is that?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This also allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: Which integer type, by chance, are you using for `number`, and has it occurred to you that it may not support 1e16 magnitude values? Likewise, you are blissfully assuming `cin>>number` actually *worked*. Check it, and check what value for `number` you got if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value limit of `int` which you're using to store your number is `2147483647`, which corresponds to 10 digits. That's why it stopped working at 11 digits. An easy workaround is to use `long long int` instead. The maximum value in this case is 2^63 which equals `9223372036854775807` (19 digits).

You can check the max value on a specific system programmatically with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long int>::max();
}
```

Output:

```
9223372036854775807
```

However I advise that you use an array of `char`s to store your number instead, as that's the optimal way to handle big numbers.

Comment: _I advise that you use an array of chars to store..._ why not a string?

Comment: Both array of chars / string would work out in this case, so it depends on your preference I guess

Answer (score 1):

In C++, an `int` has the range `-2147483648` to `2147483647` and 11 digit numbers are going out of this range. Use `long` instead of `int` when declaring the variable.